# does youtube playlists roll on when suspended

Tags: 12.04, dell, suspend, youtube

I fell asleep last night while watching a Youtube video. I woke up for a second just to see a black screen which I closed. Upon awakening I lifted the laptop screen (totally addicted to it) and heard voices before logging in. So does Youtube playlists roll on when Ubuntu is suspended or did it just start over from where it suspended? Have I been downloading all night or...???

Answer (score 2):

Suspend is something similar to hibernation BUT the system remains switched on and powered up...

I strongly believe when u'll suspend your system, the videos on Youtube will halt right away. And once u come back, they will start from the same position u left off !

Secondly, if you have merely logged out, then your background applications do continue to run. hence your youtube will continue to play even when u'll log out.

Note: This happens with my system having only one account. I don't remember weather i have explicitally made some custom setting or its by default. I am using the server edition with cinnamon on it.